# Remove views from StackScrollView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, stack

I'm trying to use the [StackScrollView class](https://github.com/raweng/StackScrollView) but I feel something important is missing here: we can add views to the stack, but we can't remove them.

Does anyone made a function to do it?

I already tried to add a nil controller but it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You remove them using by swiping. If you look at StackScrollViewController.m you'll see there is a `bounceBack:finished:context:` method which is responsible for animating the view when you go back.

If you want to bounce back programmatically (maybe you have a button for this or anything like that) you should go take a look at how the `bounceBack:finished:context:` method is used in StackScrollViewController.m

Comment: I just tried the bounceBack method, this make a little bounce but don't remove any view.

Comment: As i explained, popping view controllers programmatically isn't part of the project, user as to swipe to remove them. If you want to add a method allowing you to pop the view controller, you'll have to code it from scratch. You can take a look at handlePanFrom: and bounceBack:finished:context: to take a look at how the user's swiping is handled but understand that there is no out of the box solution.

Comment: this is why I wanted to know if someone had already made this method ^^

Comment: It is 2014 now, anybody has this method would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Just add this custom method to StackScrollViewController and then call it from where you want.

```
- (void)dismissStackViewController {

    [[[slideViews subviews] lastObject] removeFromSuperview];
}
```